# Define a permission for third-party apps to use in Android

Tags: android, permissions

I want to define a permission in my Android app, and let other third-party apps to use. This permission is used to restrict calling of my modules. That is, third-party apps must request the right permission to call my module, just like using system permissions defined by Android system, android.permission.INTERNET or so.

In my test, I defined the permission in my app, say "my.apps.permission.my_permission", and then install it on emulator. In some of my Activities, android:permission="my.apps.permission.my_permission" property is added. This property forces the apps calling my activities must have the right permission "my.apps.permission.my_permission". Then in a test app, request the permission in AndroidManifest.xml, `<uses-permission android:name="my.apps.permission.my_permission" />`

The problem is, in the test app, which will call my permission-required activities, when I call startActivity(), I got a SecurityException : Permission Denied. But, if I defined a permission with the same name in the test app, everything works fine.

And, the followings are my conclusions:

1) It seems that, the permission defined in my app, "my.apps.permission.my_permission", is not visible to other third-party apps. How to make it visible, so that other apps can use my permission just like the ones defined in Android system?

2) Even is visible, Android won't check user-defined permissions with name conflicting.(I test this by define a permission with name "android.permission.INTERNET" in test app and overrides the system-defined one, and require "android.permission.INTERNET" in my app, and still, everything works fine.) If so, every other apps can define a permission with the same name that my module requires, and cheat my app. Is that right?

Anyone can help?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look there, may it what you are looking for:

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425940/creating-your-own-permissions/21611769#21611769

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the answer.
My own app, which defined the permission for other apps to use, must be installed before other apps who want to use my permissions. Otherwise, those apps must be re-installed, to use my permissions. No other operations or codes are needed, just `<uses-permission android:name="my.apps.permission.my_permission" />`, the same as other system defined permissions.

And, several apps may define permissions with the same name, conflicting with each other. The first installed app occupies the conflicting permission name, others won't overwrite or change the original permission.

Comment: Hey MaratSafinWang, could you give a sample code for permission?

Comment: Hi @omidnazifi, use - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html for reference.