# How to set permissions in broadcast sender and receiver in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

How do we specify in broadcast sending application that which application can receive this broadcast, and in receiving application that which particular application has the permission to send broadcast to its broadcast receiver...

I am new to android..I read the documentation etc on internet but couldn't find the syntax to specify these permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use an intent filter in receiver tag in manifest

```
 <receiver
    android:name="Your receiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="action"/>
        <category android:name="category" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

To send broadcast to app

```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction("use same action in receiver");
   intent.addcategory("use same category in receiver");
   context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean that receiver will receive broadcast mentioned in the action and because of android:exported="false" this receiver is just available for the application that is sending broadcast "action"...?

Comment: How will I specify in sending application that which application is given permission to receive its broadcast?

Comment: if your receiver receiving broadcast outside application make it as true

Comment: sendBroadcast(Intent intent, String receiverPermission), how will I set the receiverPermission string here.....for example in the case of SMS this string should be "android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS", am I right?

Comment: and reciving application should be using permission with <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>...am I right?

Answer (score 89):

To control who is able to receive the broadcast message, you can use the method [sendBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
public abstract void sendBroadcast (Intent intent, String receiverPermission)
```

where you precise the name of the required permission. If the receiver does not declare this permission, it will not be able to get the message. For example, the broadcast sender can do:

```
Intent broadcast = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
sendBroadcast(broadcast, "andro.jf.mypermission");
```

In the manifest of the broadcast sender, a new permission should be declared:

```
<!--  Declaring the special permission -->
<permission android:name="andro.jf.mypermission" 
        android:label="my_permission" 
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous"></permission>
```

Then, in the application that is supposed to receive this broadcast, you have to declare this permission and say that you use it. In the manifest you can add:

```
<!--  I use the permission ! -->
<uses-permission android:name="andro.jf.mypermission"/>
```

and of course, you have to declare your broadcast receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true" />
```

You can have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8817231/1156363) for a complete example of a custom permission and also the [android developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#declaring) about this. Be carefull with the order of installation of your apps because the one that defines the permission [should be installed first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4426512/1156363).

Comment: Is it necessary that I have to use an explicit intent for this? Won't an implicit intent work in case of custom permissions?

Comment: 1. This should be the accepted answer.  2. sure you can send implicit with custom permission. he just gave example of  explicit but the main reason for permission in broadcast is when you send it implicit.   3. You don't have to install the sender app first (the app that sets the permissions) . you just have to remove the receiver app from the Ram if it was their running in background while you  installed the sender app

Comment: The self permission needs to be given by <permission> tag. Without this a self-permission cannot be used, it will block the broadcast but it will not allow it too.

Comment: what is the differences between "protected-broadcast" and the permission settings above? It seems "protected-broadcast" is purely just redundant

Answer (score 47):

If you want to restrict who only can send intents to your broadcast receiver, do it this way:

The broadcast **receiver**:

```
<manifest ...>

    <!-- Permission declaration -->
    <permission android:name="my.app.PERMISSION" />

    <receiver 
        android:name="my.app.BroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="my.app.PERMISSION"> <!-- Permission enforcement for delivering intents to this receiver -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="my.app.Action" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    ...
</manifest>
```

The broadcast **sender**:

```
<manifest ...>
    <!-- We declare we own the permission to send broadcast to the above receiver -->
    <uses-permission android:name="my.app.PERMISSION" />

    ...
</manifest>
```

Sending broadcast from the **sender** Activity to the **receiver**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("my.app.Action");
activity.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

If you declare the permission like this:

```
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="my.app.PERMISSION" />
```

Then the **sender** will be able to use this permission and send broadcasts to receiver only when both the **sender** and the **receiver** apps are signed by the same developer certificate.

Comment: <permission android:name="my.app.PERMISSION" /> 
should be in Broadcast sender and
<uses-permission android:name="my.app.PERMISSION" /> in Broadcast Receiver

Comment: +1 with a small addition <uses-permission android:name="my.app.PERMISSION" /> to both sender and receiver. Without that mine was not working

Answer (score 13):

### Declare permission

First you need declare your permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<permission android:name="YOUR_PERMISSION_STRING" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.codylab.photogallery.PRIVATE"/>
```

`the android:name` value is used as permission value and will used later.

### Usage

There are two kinds of permission usages related to broadcast receiver:

(1) Control which application can receive your broadcast:

```
String PERMISSION_STRING_PRIVATE_RECEIVER = "YOU_NEED_THIS_TO_RECEIVE_THIS_BROADCAST"
sendBroadcast(intent, PERMISSION_STRING_PRIVATE_RECEIVER);
```

With this usage, you can control only authorized application can handle the broadcast you sent.

(2) Only handle the broadcasts have the specified permission

```
String PERMISSION_STRING_PRIVATE_BROADCASTER = "ONLY HANDLE BROADCASTS WITH THIS PERMISSION"
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_SAMPLE);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter, PERMISSION_STRING_PRIVATE_BROADCASTER, null);
```

With this usage, you can make sure that the broadcaster is authorized.

Comment: That is the only answer with example that doesn't require a declaration of the broadcast receiver in the manifest file. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

After half day search and test, based on @JFL's answer, I find the sender app must add both `<permission>` tag and `<uses-permission>` tag, then the receiver can receive the broadcast with permission. Otherwise, the receiver app won't receive the broadcast.