# permission is not working in Broadcast in android

Tags: android, android-broadcast

Here i have registered my .Reciever_

```
<receiver 
    android:name=".Reciever_"
    android:permission="com.paad.MY_BROADCAST_PERMISSION">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="com.paad.action.NEW_LIFEFORM_"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and i want to use this `android:permission` in my code but it is not working .

I am using this permission in my code

```
String requiredPermission = "com.paad.MY_BROADCAST_PERMISSION";
```

i want to send my ordered broadcast .

```
sendOrderedBroadcast( new Intent("com.paad.action.NEW_LIFEFORM_") , requiredPermission ) ;
```

program control is not going inside OnRecieve() method ?

Comment: did you declared this permission in your manifest?

Comment: it is not working i have also , declared it in <permission>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15316487/2285292 , helps me .... thanks JFL for this valuable answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below link its same as like your problem....

[How to set permissions in broadcast sender and receiver in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770794/how-to-set-permissions-in-broadcast-sender-and-receiver-in-android)

In the **manifest** of the broadcast sender, a new permission should be declared:

```
<permission android:name="com.paad.MY_BROADCAST_PERMISSION"></permission>

<uses-permission android:name="com.paad.MY_BROADCAST_PERMISSION"/>
```

its same like your code

```
<receiver 
    android:name=".Reciever_"
    android:permission="com.paad.MY_BROADCAST_PERMISSION">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="com.paad.action.NEW_LIFEFORM_"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Thanks