# send broadcast restricted to dynamic list of applications

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions, inter-process-communicat

my application defines events that other apps installed on the device could be registered to (like other apps can register to google play services location updates and activity recognition events).

google play services process notify this types of events via `PendingIntent` provided by the receiving app.

I prefer to do it by [sending a broadcast restricted by permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770794/how-to-set-permissions-in-broadcast-sender-and-receiver-in-android), and I think that from a good reason: `PendingIntent` cannot be saved in persistent way, so every time my app will shout down, the apps that that registered to my events will have to re-register to my events..

the problem:  [in the link I provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770794/how-to-set-permissions-in-broadcast-sender-and-receiver-in-android), you can see how to restrict broadcast by custom permission declared in both sides (the broadcast sender application, and the receiving application), but what if I need to decide from the senders side dynamically from a list I'm getting from the server, what are the apps that allowed to receive the broadcast?

I don't find any reference or example in the web how to do so.

I guess it suppose to be possible somehow, because seems like google play services is using this approach for notifying GCM push notifications only to the relevant receiver...

please help me understand how can I do such a thing.

Comment: why this question deserves downvotes?

Comment: Not my downvotes but my guess the reason is 'To reproduce the problem there must be code.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but what if I need to decide from the senders side dynamically from a list I'm getting from the server, what are the apps that allowed to receive the broadcast? I don't find any reference or example in the web how to do so.

Use an explicit `Intent`, where you have set the `ComponentName` of the specific `BroadcastReceiver` that you are "broadcasting" to. You will need to "broadcast" such an explicit `Intent` once per app that is "allowed to receive the broadcast".

Comment: perfect!  I'll do that!