# Android GCM Send Permission works without uses-permission

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging, android-permissions

Take a look at the sample manifest here - https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

My question is howcome the receiver receives broadcast with the permission `android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"` when no `uses-permission` or `permission` tag is used with the same string ?

-- solved --

Note: don't forget to read the comments in the selected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is the one *defending* itself with the permission.

The sender -- in this case, something in Google Play Services that handles the GCM connection -- is the one that needs to hold the permission, via `<uses-permission>` or the equivalent.

The `<permission>` itself is being defined by Google Play Services, presumably, given the permission name.

Comment: So what you're saying is Google play services (sender) app contains the `uses-permission` as well as the `permission` tags defining the permission string. All I have to do is use it in the receiver tag and then I'll be able to receive broadcasts from the sender app.

So in order to test this, I created 2 apps A and B. A has a broadcast receiver. Here's how the manifest (and code) for both looks like - http://pastie.org/private/hqoapkl7wiuksjmpdo0dga

I mentioned the problem in there, which is, A doesn't receives broadcast from B. What am I doing wrong or failing to understand ?

Comment: @user1437328: There is nothing in that code that has anything to do with GCM. If you want this to work, get rid of the second parameter to `sendBroadcast()` and ensure that B is installed before A.

Comment: I agree that has nothing to do with GCM, but for the sake of testing similar situation I wrote my own piece to understand. I'll do what you said and see if the broadcast works or not.

Comment: ok, this seems to work (although I'll test more). Seems like the key was to remove the second argument from `sendBroadcast()`. This is a little strange as the [Security](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#Security) guide mentions the usage of second argument. So does this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15316487) which is a slightly different example (or maybe not as the only difference is I put `uses-permission` tag in the sender app manifest (B) rather than the receiver app manifest (A). Any idea why the second argument had to be removed ?

Comment: @user1437328: "Seems like the key was to remove the second argument from sendBroadcast()" -- those are for different roles. In the GCM scenario, the *receiver* is defending itself against rogue *senders*. In the two-parameter `sendBroadcast()` scenario, the *sender* is defending itself against rogue *receivers*.